# Why calling .count() on Queryable would make the .ToList() returning 0 rows?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, class, iqueryable

```
query = query.DistinctBy(q => q.Series.Name)
    .OrderBy(c => c.Series.RoleId.Value == (int)Type.Type1 ? 0 : 1)
    .ThenBy(c => c.Series.RoleId.Value == (int)Type.Type2 ? 0 : 1)
    .ThenBy(s => s.Series.RoleId)
    .AsQueryable();
}

query = query
    .OrderByDescending(a => a.Series.Date)
    .ThenByDescending(a => a.Series.Id);

var total = query.Count();

var states = query
    .Skip((model.pageNumber - 1) * model.pageSize)
    .Take(model.pageSize);
    
var return = Mapper.Map<List<SeriesDTO>>(states);
```

It's mind boggling. I need the count of result set before it gets paginated using `skip` and `take`.

But this `query.count()` returns 0 unless I write
`query.ToList().Count()` which return the count but

```
var return = Mapper.Map<List<SeriesDTO>>(states);`
```

return no row. When I change back `query.ToList().Count()` to`query.Count()` then it works.

Also i tried

```
var states = query
    .Skip((model.pageNumber - 1) * model.pageSize)
    .Take(model.pageSize)
    .ToList();
```

but same issue.

I need to have the total count of the result set right before i do `Skip` and `Take`

Comment: How is `query` constructed?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] including the construction of `query` and the explanation of where the data comes from. Also, which `DistinctBy()` do you call?

Comment: could you also provide you `AutoMapper` configuration?

Answer (score 2):

Seems you have multiple issues in your code.

To diagnose the problem I recommend to share the code you use to construct the `query` and data sample.

As for second part of your issue

> But this query.count() returns 0 unless I write query.ToList().Count() which return the count but `var return = Mapper.Map<List<SeriesDTO>>(states);` return no row.

Seems you misunderstand the `Automapper` usage. `Map()` cannot proceed on `IQueriable` or `IOrderedQueriable`.

To fix this you need to call `query.ToList()` before the `Map()`. Another way is to use `ProjectTo()` which is preferrable as it allows to optimize select statement, see details [here](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html).

Comment: _"Map() cannot proceed on IQueriable or IOrderedQueriable."_ - so it's not AutoMapper then, or an adapter thereof. Otherwise it wouldn't compile, let alone return a count of 0.

Comment: Technically the author could create the mapping `CreateMap<IQueriable, List<SeriesDTO>()` to avoid runtime exceptions. But never tried that case.. Anyway, we expect other details